# Missing dependency libmysqlclient.so.16 on Centos 5.7

Tags: mysql, centos, library

I have an app compiled on (32 bit) Centos 6.2, which I need to run on Centos 5.7 but it complains that it needs ***libmysqlclient.so.16***

I'm not sure where to find this file (I tried "yum provides" but nothing provides it). I have the epel repo enabled but nothing there either.

Can someone advise on how to add this? (Or is this even possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql.com apparently offers a "compat" package for RHEL5 that has these libraries:

```
$ rpm -qlp MySQL-shared-compat-5.1.49-1.rhel5.i386.rpm
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.10
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.10.0.0
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.12
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.12.0.0
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.14
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.14.0.0
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.15
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.15.0.0
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.16
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.10
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.10.0.0
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.12
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.12.0.0
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.14
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.14.0.0
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.15
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.15.0.0
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.16
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0
```

The download link is: http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/mysql-5.1/MySQL-shared-compat-5.1.49-1.rhel5.i386.rpm

I haven't tried this, so I'm not sure how well it will work.

Comment: It looks like this is just the beginning though.  Using the ldd command I see more dependencies:  libssl.so.10 => not found, libcrypto.so.10 => not found, libsybdb.so.5 => not found.  Does this mean I should give up or do the same for all of these packages?

Comment: Hmm.  This is going to be problematic, since you will probably break a bunch of things if you try to upgrade the CentOS5 packages with CentOS6 ones. The MySQL library only works because MySQL saw fit to provide these compatibility libraries; there's no guarantee any other project will do so.  At this point, it may be best to recompile to CentOS5.  If that's not possible, you should seriously consider using CentOS6.  That may be easier than trying to shoehorn newer libraries into the older OS version.

Comment: If this is pre-packaged software, does the vendor stipulate a specific RedHat version? Basically, your setup may not meet the minimum requirements. Is there a version compiled for RHEL5?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to install the following package:

```
$ yum install mysql-devel
```

If you already have a different file `libmysqlclient.so.15`, this means you need to install a different version of `mysql-devel` to get this file. I think you have to modify your application if possible or install the older version of mysql-devel.

This is a dirty workaround you can try which is to create a symlink from libmysqlclient.so.15 to libmysqlclient.so.16. I am not sure about the result. You can try it on your own :)

Comment: Nope - already have that in, and it offers /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.15

Answer (score 0):

While installing ‘mysql’ module for PHP 5.4 (yum install php54w-mysql*), I encountered the following error:

```
Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16) is needed by package php-mysql-package-version
```

Hence, I downloaded an 'compat' rpm, which installed all the different versions of
libmysqlclient.so.{12,14,15,16} and after that MySQL module got installed without any issues.

You may refer [this link](https://gettechgo.wordpress.com/2012/12/03/failed-dependency-libmysqlcliet-so-16/) to find detailed instructions.